# Is that the good thing to create object in same class itself ? does it make any memory leakage issue in .net

Tags: c#

for e.g I have a class student and in same class the object is created itself.

```
class student 
{
     public static void Main ()
     {
         //......
         //......
     }

     student s= new student();
}
```

Comment: What are you aiming to achieve, could you explain what the problem is? What you are doing is technically fine and is used for the singleton pattern but really depends on what you are doing

Comment: As gunner has said, it is perfectly fine, I have used it in lots of different instances, such as conversion methods, clone methods. You will likely only come into complications if you do it in a constructor without as this will cause an infinite loop if there isn't anywhere to break out of it.

Comment: No it's not. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Verarind - The OP's code works perfectly fine as is. Can you explain why you say it doesn't work?

Comment: @Enigmativity How can you say that it works? It will produce a StackOverflowException.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - Whoops! I compiled the code, but forgot to instantiate an instance of `student`. I've been at this for too long to have made that mistake.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes the code will work but you can't access `s`. `s` is private and not static and you can't create an instance of student in `static void Main()` because it causes a StackOverflowException. The variable `s` is absolutally inaccessible. Maybe I didn't understand the code but I tried it and I don't see any way to use `s`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you very much but I got a downvote for my answer and I didn't understand why. Maybe Enigmativity will explain it to me.

Comment: @Verarind - Sorry, I made a mistake testing the code, so I thought your answer was wrong. I went back to up-vote but SO says my vote is locked unless the answer is edited. If you make a minor change I will happily up-vote.

Comment: @Enigmativity No Problem. I did a small edit but anyone does an upvote and after that my answer doesn't have a downvote anymore. For me its fine now. I only needed a comprehensible reason for downvotes. In my opinion should everyone that downvotes a question or answer leave a comment why he downvoted it. I think that's the only way to get better.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare the class as your sample code shows it will not work.

You use an initializer that creates an instance (of the same type) that will call the initializer that creates an instance that will call the initializer... 
You'll end up in an StackOverflowException.

If you need a nested structure of the same kind you should think of creating it lazy on first access.

Maybe the code could look like this:

```
class student
{
    Lazy<student> s = new Lazy<student>(() => new student());
}
```

This will give you the possibility to create an instance. At the first access of `s.Value` a new instance of student will be created. The logik of iterating over all instances will create an StackOverflowException or not.

A singleton is created as a static variable.

```
class StudentSingleton
{
    public static readonly StudentSingleton Instance = new StudentSingleton();

    private StudentSingleton() { }
}
```

The difference is that there is no instance variable created of the same kind.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
{ 
    public A InstanceA{get; set;}
}
```

It's called self-association and though it is a common practice in some cases but you'd better avoid using it without a good cause.

Check this for example:

http://sce.uhcl.edu/helm/rationalunifiedprocess/process/modguide/md_assoc.htm#Self-Associations

Some example:

```
public class Person
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public DateTime BirthDay {get; set;}
   //    ...  some other properties

   public Person Father {get; set;}
   public Person Mother {get; set;}
}
```

Here we use self-association in class because instance of Person in analogy to real life certainly knows who his parents are and they are Persons too.

As to your case just change code to:

```
class Student 
{
}

class Program
{
     public static void Main ()
     {
         //......
         //......
         Student s = new Student();
     }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm too stupid to understand your code. `field` is an instance variable, right? To access `field` I need an instance of `A`, right? I tested your code and if I wrote `new A()` in a static method contained in `A` and call that method or outside of `A` I'll get a StackOverflowException. How can I use your Code?

Comment: Okay my comment refered to code that has been edited.